# Call LINQ or replicate Collection.Add on Javascript event - plain JS or Jquery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a quick question about Javascript, Razor and C#. Essentially the idea is this:

1. User checks the box he/she wants multiple entries
2. Hidden partial view gets shown using Javascript. That partial view is saved on a Javascript variable so later on when the user clicks a button it can be appended to the DOM again - for adding another entry
3. On click of another button, Save the data the user types to the C# collection property - this is the part I'm stuck in :)

We can't do this LINQ in Javascript

```
@Model.MyCollection.Add(item) - how do I replicate the behavior?
```

then later send it all to the controller on form submit :)

I can only use Razor, Javascript, and Jquery. I can't make a call to the server for a fresh partial view. This would've been very easy with a front-end framework but we're not allowed :( Or maybe because I'm not razor sharp with c# razor yet :)

Comment: You can just create a hidden field or even update one of the fields generated from your viewmodel with javascript. When the form is submitted, the updated field should get sent along with it.

Comment: @itsme86 yup, we want to add items to the collection though..I haven't done that using just javascript :)

Comment: You can't add items to the collection with javascript because the collection doesn't exist at the client. The collection is used by the server to render the page which is sent to the client. The client never sees the "collection". It just sees the rendered page with the collection already turned into HTML elements. Hit View Source in your browser on your page and you'll see what I'm talking about.

Comment: @itsme86 yup that is what I'm stuck on, how to replicate that behavior... Add something to a model, then send it to controller, with Angular,knockout etc that would've been straightforward

Comment: If you just add to the form field that is associated with MyCollection, it will be picked up by the controller when the form is submitted. If there's no form field for it, create a hidden form field for MyCollection.

Comment: @itsme86 Ohhh...maybe I'm so used with the frameworks and not trust the c# plumbing enough :) will do that, simple push to a javascript array then it should be happy..Thanks for the suggestion!